# Browser Calling to agent conferencing

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, voice, conference

i have a question, i'm triggering a call from a browser to "customer 1".  Now when a callback reaches my application url.  What i want to implement is a agent conferencing (to be able to have the capability of live transfer).

now, in the callback, i return a twiml response

```
$dial = $response->dial('');
$dial->conference('my-conference', array(
                'startConferenceOnEnter' => true,
                'endConferenceOnExit' => false,
            ));
```

This would in effect put the browser call in the conference.

My question now are the following:

1. How do i call the 'customer' and include it in the conference?
2. I notice that when the 'customer' rejects that call, the initial caller "agent" would still be in the conference waiting, how do i end the call automatically.
3. While the "agent" is waiting, can i listen to the "outbound ringing" to the "customer" as per the "earlyMedia" flag of agent conference.
4. If i include another "agent" in the call, where both agent have endConferenceOnExit => true, would it end the call if agent1 drops the call while agent2 is still in the call?